# Image Orientation using Volley Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, orientation, android-volley

I have an app which need to download multiple small images. So, I use the VolleyLibrary. But I have a problem.
When I download images sometimes, the images aren't in the correct orientation. So I tried to use ExifInterface, but I can't because ImageRequest from Volley only returns a bitmap or an error. And Bitmap object can't give me orientation.
So can I use Volley to download image and rotate them correctly ?

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Answer (score 1):

just encounter the same error, don't know why Volley return a rotated image but I resolved with this:

```
if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
    Bitmap bMapRotate=null;
    Matrix mat=new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(90);
    bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
} else {
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: I have am Android client and an iOS client updating a profile image on my server. Images received through a volley image request from iOS clients are rotated, and android ones are not. I cannot apply a one size fits all solution like this. Does anyone have more information what might cause this behavior?